# TestCafe not running in ubuntu on headless and UI mode

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, testcafe, webautomation

Testcafe tests are not running in Ubuntu(AWS machine)

I have executed the following commands for all the available browsers

```
testcafe "chrome" abc.js
testcafe "chrome:headless" abc.js

testcafe "firefox" abc.js
testcafe "firefox:headless" abc.js

testcafe "chromium" abc.js
testcafe "chromium:headless" abc.js
```

I have got the following error message which executing testcafe commands

> ERROR: No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive.

Answer (score 5):

> `ERROR Was unable to open the browser "chrome:headless" due to error. Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/testcafe/chrome-profile`

It looks like you are trying to run TestCafe without a superuser after the `sudo` run.

I suggest you delete the `/tmp/testcafe` folder (`sudo rm -rf /tmp/testcafe`) and run TestCafe again (without `sudo`).

Comment: we had the error `ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.` and this solution fixed it

Comment: I also had the above error and this did *not* fix the error

Comment: Thanks Man!
You gave the solution man, I was head butting for last 4 hours!, big cheer!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The command : `testcafe "chrome" abc.js` means that the file `abc.js` must be in the current working directory in order for `testcafe` command to find this file.

if `abc.js` is in a subfolder the command line should be:

`testcafe "chrome" ./**/abc.js`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried the above given command and getting the following error message. `ERROR Was unable to open the browser "chrome:headless" due to error.

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/tmp/testcafe/chrome-profile`